# Waiting for Robospice requests to finish

Tags: android, json, spring, robospice

I'm using Robospice in my Android app to get data in JSON format from the server. When the user logs in for the first time, I would like to perform few requests to get data needed for the first run and only after that redirect the user to a certain activity.

How can I "wait" for the Robospice request to finish?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the result of your Robospice request on your requestListener, so you should start performing your requests at your onRequestSuccess method of your customRequestListener

Comment: I doing it that way but I need to start activity only after few requests are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). When it reaches 0, then start your activity.